# Magento Event Observer: modify CatalogSearch to include custom attribute

Tags: events, magento, search, catalog, observers

I was following the article (Customize Magento using Event/Observer) on the below link:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method#step_7

But not sure about the step 7. How could I do the step 7 on this article?

**Step 7**
Navigate to the product details page on the front end and observe that the new discount has taken effect. To be noted here is that, on all other screens where discounted price is required. An example here is the search results screen, where you would need to add this new attribute to the select query search attributes in method

```
Mage_CatalogSearch_Block_Result→_getProductCollection()

$_productCollection= $_productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('percent_discount');
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be a lot easier if you could just navigate to product attributes management and set 'Used in Product Listing' to 'Yes' this way, you are able to read the attribute value on product list page.